# package-info.java + Hibernate annotation @TypeDefs + Maven

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, orm, package-info

How can I declare @TypeDefs on separate package-info.java class and use it package level with @Type. Currently I have declared it according to following manner. But when I compile the application with Maven it will give following error. Thanks.

**package-info.java class**

```
@TypeDefs
        ({
                @TypeDef(
                        name="encryptedString",
                        typeClass=EncryptedStringType.class,
                        parameters={
                                @Parameter(name="encryptorRegisteredName",
                                        value="rcmHibernateStringEncryptor")
                        }
                )
        })

package com.core.model;
import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef;
import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDefs;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter;
import org.jasypt.hibernate4.type.EncryptedStringType;
```

**Maven Error**

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project MyApp: Compilation failure
[ERROR] com\core\model\package-infor.java:[2,0] error: package annotations should be in file package-info.java
```

Comment: This `com\core\model\package-infor.java` looks suspicious

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to rename `package-infor.java` to `package-info.java`

Which should contain the following:

```
@TypeDefs({
    @TypeDef(
        name="encryptedString",
        typeClass=EncryptedStringType.class,
        parameters={
            @Parameter(name="encryptorRegisteredName",
                value="rcmHibernateStringEncryptor")
        }
    )
})    
package com.core.model;
import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef;
import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDefs;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter;
import org.jasypt.hibernate4.type.EncryptedStringType;
```